# Fake/mock Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have CyanogenMod installed on an LG2 without Gapps. I only use open-source software — except the Slack app, which I restored from a backup

The Slack app works perfectly fine, but always asks me to install "Google Play Services". I just ignore this and it works.

Would it be possible to mock/fake the Google Play API somehow, so that whenever Slack asks for "Are the Google Play Services installed" the fake API would return `true`?

I am not an Android Developer - I know Java and Linux so becoming one should be possible to solve this little problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic as _"questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."_ See the StackOverflow help guide on being on-topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Faking GPservices would not help because the reason slack needs GP services is for push notifications. Slack sends all your messages to google and google then sends a push to your phone.  This is supposedly for battery efficiency but it seems extremely suspicious.

Comment: You will notice that without GPservices you will not get notifications from slack or most apps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue on Slack's side aswell.
I've already reported it. So they might try to make it so that app looks if google services exist on the system, then tries to use it. It supposes to fix the annoying alert about Google Services not being istalled.

About the mocking thing.
There are people already working on it.
Might be worth looking into https://fralef.me/using-android-without-google-apps.html

Comment: The website is down. What was the name of the service?

Comment: @JoshuaRobison https://web.archive.org/web/20160505101855/https://fralef.me/using-android-without-google-apps.html

Answer (score 2):

[microG](https://microg.org/) (requires root and a ROM with support for [signature spoofing](https://github.com/microg/android_packages_apps_GmsCore/wiki/Signature-Spoofing) or [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/) with FakeGApps module) aims to be an open "re-implementation" of Google Play Services, but the project is at alpha-stage and [missing intended features](https://github.com/microg/android_packages_apps_GmsCore/wiki/Implementation-Status). I've successfully spoofed GSF in applications which nag about missing Google Play Services and may otherwise be non-functional.

Comment: I thought microG was just a sandboxed version of GPservices. If it is infact a spoof system, it could actually be great for privacy.